# Multiline Regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract all text between two keywords(<<-DOC, DOC) from a file.
For example, if my file content is as below

abc.rb

```
def abc
    <<-DOC abc:
        return "hahaha"
    DOC
    puts "hahaha"
end

def efg
    <<-DOC efg:
        return "hehehe"
    DOC
    puts "hehehe"
end
```

I want to get two matches:

```
<<-DOC abc:
    return "hahaha"
DOC
```

and

```
<<-DOC efg:
    return "hehehe"
DOC
```

I tried `File.read("abc.rb").match(/<<-DOC(.*?)DOC/m)`
but it gives all text between first occurrence of `<<-DOC` (inside abc) and last occurrence of `DOC` (inside efg)

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://rubular.com/r/h5onSBTDOz

Comment: abc.rb is not actually run right? It's just being used as a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, your regex is correct and the (.*?) should be a non-greedy match.  I think that the issue you are running into is that `match` in Ruby only returns the first match of the regex.  For instance

```
File.read("abc.rb").match(/<<-DOC(.*?)DOC/m)
=> #<MatchData "<<-DOC abc:\n        return \"hahaha\"\n    DOC" 1:" abc:\n        return \"hahaha\"\n    ">
```

What you really want to use is `scan`

```
File.read("abc.rb").scan(/<<-DOC(.*?)DOC/m)
=> [[" abc:\n        return \"hahaha\"\n    "], [" efg:\n        return \"hehehe\"\n    "]]
```

This will return you an array of arrays, with each array containing the captured groups from the regex.  See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan

Answer (score 2):

[Flip-flop](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2018/02/22/flip-flop-real-application) solution:

```
File.readlines("abc.rb").select do |line|
  true if (line.include? '<<-DOC')...(line.include? 'DOC')
end
#⇒ [
#     [0] "    <<-DOC abc:",
#     [1] "        return \"hahaha\"",
#     [2] "    DOC",
#     [3] "    <<-DOC efg:",
#     [4] "        return \"hehehe\"",
#     [5] "    DOC"
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about Flip-flop in ruby.